Mysql sum joined table
Hello I am new to mysql  have two tables
order
with the following data



No
Customer




1
A


1
c


2
b



second table is



Customer
Amount




A
1


A
2


C
7


B
5



the two table ara joined by customer
I want to sum the amount grouped by No
The result expected is: Details



No
Customers
Amount




1
A,c
10


2
b
5




You can use group_concat
select t1.No, group_concat(distinct t1.Customer) Customers,sum(Amount) Amount 
from tbl1 t1
join tbl2 t2 on t1.Customer = t2.Customer
group by t1.No 

